# Apple Wallet NFC-Enabled Pass use cases

Tags: ios, nfc, applepay, wallet, passkit

We are trying to bring Apple Wallet NFC-Enabled Pass based loyalty card program to a territory without Apple Pay support. In order to build a strong use case for Apple representatives we are trying to gather a list of merchants who are using Apple Wallet NFC-Enabled Passes without supporting Apple Pay. Both in territories with Apple Pay and without.

Is it possible to support Apple Wallet NFC Passes without supporting Apple Pay? If yes, an example of someone doing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe that there is any requirement for Apple Pay to be supported in order to support NFC loyalty cards in the wallet. Woolworths Supermarkets in Australia has enabled NFC loyalty cards in the Apple wallet, while Apple Pay is supported on nearly all payment terminals in Australia (some very old tap and pay readers don't work) only the supermarket terminals are enabled for the loyalty card. The same company owns department stores and although the loyalty card is accepted there you must scan a barcode, you cannot use NFC. You can use Apple Pay there though

Comment: [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW1) refers to sending loyalty cards as part of an Apple Pay transaction, but in the case of the supermarket the loyalty card transaction is separate; it happens prior to payment. A subsequent payment is made in cash, credit card or Apple Pay.

Answer (score 5):

There is no requirement to support Apple Pay in order to support reading Apple Wallet passes.

> An example of someone doing it would be greatly appreciated.

http://passninja.com/

Disclosure: I work for [Flomio](http://www.flomio.com/), the company behind PassNinja.

Comment: How about guiding us through the working of passninja.